# Find the best coefficient variables for array java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to get the sum of all elements in the array and multiply it by its index+1

Then I want to add all of these sums to create a total sum

however if the current indexes sum is not larger than the previous sum don't add it to the end total as it is a bad value (add all the values that aren't bad) and return the result

````
```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class Main {

public static int[] solve(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0)
        return new int[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] *= i + 1;

    int start = 0;
    List<Integer> result = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int num: arr)
        if (num >= start) {
            result.add(num);
            start += num;
        }


    int[] found = result.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
    return found;
}


public static void main(String[] args)

{

    int [] array = {-1,3,4};
    int total=0;
   int[] array2= solve(array);
    for(int i=0; i<array2.length; i++){
       // System.out.println(i+"\t"+array2[i]);
        total+=array2[i];
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}

```
````

output should be 17 it is 18

Comment: Do you just want to calculate the sum under your condition or find the best combination of the array with largest sum?

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm reading this right you take in an array of numbers, multiply each one by its index + 1, then remove any that are not in increasing order? I'm not sure what the question is, but you should try to break the problem into steps to make it easier to approach.

```java
int[] arr = {6, 2, 4, 4, 5};

// Maybe this is what you were trying to do?
public static int[] solve(int[] arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0)
        return new int[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] *= i + 1;

    int start = 0;
    List<Integer> result = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int num: arr)
        if (num >= start) {
            result.add(num);
            start += num;
        }
    return result.toArray();
}
```

Comment: I get an error when I run that code return result.toArray(); incompatible types required int[] found java.lang.Object[] so I can't test the code to see if it is what I wanted can't be converted to int[]

Comment: @James try this one `int[] found = result.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray()`